# Single window's style different than system's

Tags: .net, windows, coding-style, themes

Is it possibile to set a single window's style differently than system? E.g. I have silver WinXP, but I'd like my app window to 'believe' it should paint itself in blue - can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the standard theme engine. To achieve that you'll need to use a third party skinning engine.

Comment: @brovar I would also offer a mild word of caution.  A lot of people have problems with skinning engines, rendering bugs, sporadic crashes etc.  I'm sure there are good ones, but it's very very hard to do well. If you can stick to the system theming then you'll not have to worry about that.